# How to animate shared element ImageView from ListView fragment to detail view fragment in a master/detail pane layout

Tags: android, animation, master-detail, shared-element-transition, fragment-transitions

My application tablet layout contains a grid view (RecyclerView) on the left containing a grid of images, and a details view on the right which displays a smaller version of the currently selected grid view image along with additional text views describing that image. I am trying to figure out how to provide a shared element animation transition that will slide and scale any clicked image view (in the left-hand-side grid view fragment) to its matching location in the details view fragment. My application only needs an "enter" transition because I do not want each each image selection to be recorded on the back-stack.

I have tried using the standard shared element support calls in my `OnItemClick(View view)` handler as follows:

```
DetailFragment detailFragment = detailFragment.newInstance(mFragmentId);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    movieDetailFragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(
            TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(
                    R.transition.change_image_transform));
            view.setTransitionName(getString(
                    R.string.image_transition_name));
}

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.detail_container,
                 detailFragment,
                 DETAIL_FRAGMENT_TAG)
        .addSharedElement(view, getString(R.string.image_transition_name))
        .commit();
```

The "view" variable is the ImageView that the user clicked in the grid view. The `onCreate()` method of my detail fragment also contains the entry

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    mImageView.setTransitionName(
            getString(R.string.image_transition_name));
}
```

I am also using the following change_image_transform.xml transition set:

```
<transitionSet>
    <changeImageTransform/>
    <changeBounds/>
</transitionSet>
```

along with

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
<item name="android:windowActivityTransitions">true</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
<item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">
    @transition/change_image_transform</item>
```

All these settings work properly for single pane mode. When the user clicks on an image in the grid view activity, the detail fragment (in a new activity) replaces the grid view and the animation works perfectly for both enter and return scenarios.

In 2 pane mode however, the image does not slide and scale from its source in the grid view to it's destination in the newly created detail fragment. I believe that the problem I am having is due to the fact that the source ImageView lives in the permanently visible grid view fragment, and therefore does not get included in the animation framework's transition handling.

My searching has not turned up any clear answer to this problem other than one vague recommendation to use a simple custom animation. I tried a simple TranslateAnimation (without scaling) just as a test, but this had 2 problems: it would not allow the image cross the grid view fragment's border, and it had the undesirable side-effect of actually "moving" the image (leaving a temporary empty spot it my grid view while the animation was being performed). Ultimately, the desired effect is to see the image slide and scale from is source to destination without causing the original image to be erased.

Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I decided that the simplest way to get a shared element transition to work between two fragments in 2 pane mode was to simply do the animation myself. In my solution, I do not replace the detail fragment with the details of the selected grid image; instead I just refresh the layout controls with new data from the selected grid item. To prevent the parent linear layout from resizing when the target ImageView is temporarily removed from the detail view and placed in the overlay (for animation), the ImageView parent is forced to size of contained child and then restored to its original layout width and height after the animation. Here is the function that performs the animation in response to a grid item click event:

```
/**
 * Sets up and runs an animation that translates and scales the
 * selected poster in the grid view to the poster ImageView in the
 * detail fragment.
 * @param srcView
 * @param destView
 */
private void runAnimation(final ImageView srcView, final ImageView destView) {
    final ViewGroup destParentView = (ViewGroup)destView.getParent();

    // Set the destination image view's parent (FrameLayout) to
    // keep the width and height of image view that will be
    // temporarily re-parented during the animation. This will
    // ensure that the enclosing LinearLayout will remain fixed
    // in appearance during the animation.
    final int parentLayoutWidth = destParentView.getLayoutParams().width;
    final int parentLayoutHeight = destParentView.getLayoutParams().height;
    destParentView.getLayoutParams().width = destParentView.getMeasuredWidth();
    destParentView.getLayoutParams().height = destParentView.getMeasuredHeight();

    // Scale the destination image to the size of
    // the source image. The animation will restore
    // the destination image scale when it is run.
    // Note that the scale needs to be set before any
    // translation so that the translation takes into
    // account the change in scale.
    float scaleX = (float)destView.getMeasuredWidth()
            / (float)srcView.getMeasuredWidth();
    float scaleY = (float) destView.getMeasuredHeight()
            / (float) srcView.getMeasuredHeight();

    destView.setScaleX(1f / scaleX);
    destView.setScaleY(1f / scaleY);

    // Now set translation on scaled image so that the
    // destination image begins at the same position as
    // the source image. The destination image translation
    // will be returned to 0 during the animation.
    int[] srcLocation = {0, 0};
    int[] dstLocation = {0, 0};
    srcView.getLocationOnScreen(srcLocation);
    destView.getLocationOnScreen(dstLocation);
    destView.setTranslationX(srcLocation[0] - dstLocation[0]);
    destView.setTranslationY(srcLocation[1] - dstLocation[1]);

    // The overlay must be created from any view whose bounds
    // encompasses both the source and destination views.
    final ViewGroup rootView =
                (ViewGroup)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.main_content);
    rootView.getOverlay().add(destView);

    // Run animation and when it completes, move the destination
    // view from the overlay back to it's original parent. Also,
    // restore the parent's layout params which were changed to
    // act as a placeholder with the image was being animated.
    destView.animate()
            .scaleX(1f)
            .scaleY(1f)
            .translationX(0)
            .translationY(0)
            .setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator(2))
            .setDuration(500)
            .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    rootView.getOverlay().remove(destView);
                    destParentView.getLayoutParams().width = parentLayoutWidth;
                    destParentView.getLayoutParams().height = parentLayoutHeight;
                    destParentView.addView(destView);
                }
            });
}
```